# SwiftUI: How to block certain characters in a textfield?

Tags: swift, swiftui

i have a url address bar in my app that only loads urls in this format "www.google.com" instead of "https://www.google.com"

```
@State private var text = ""
@State private var site = "www.google.com/"

    TextField("Enter a URL", text: $text, onCommit: {
            guard !text.isEmpty else {return}
            site = text
        })
```

I want the Textfield to block out these characters "https://" so that whenever a user copies and pastes a url from another browser, they don't have to manually delete "https://" every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    @State var txt = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter Url", text: Binding(
            get: { txt },
            set: { newValue in
                if trim(newValue).starts(with: "https://") {
                    txt = String(trim(newValue).dropFirst(8))
                } else {
                    txt = newValue
                }
            }
        ))
    }
    
    func trim(_ str: String) -> String {
        return str.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}
```