# SwiftUI: WebKit is loading page continuously when typing url

Tags: swift, swiftui, webkit

This is a URL address bar in my macOS app that was working fine with this TextField:

```
@State private var text = ""
@State private var site = "www.google.com/" //stored as two separate values so that WebKit isn't trying to continuously load a URL with every single keystroke. The "site" property is only updated once the user presses the return key.

var body: some View {

let webView = WebView(site: $site, text: $text)
    
        TextField("Enter a URL", text: $text, onCommit: {
                guard !text.isEmpty else {return}
                site = text
            })
             webView //To display the loaded web page
                    }
```

..But after implementing a [trim function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68600043/swiftui-how-to-block-certain-characters-in-a-textfield) that removes "https://" when a user copies and pastes a URL onto the address bar, WebKit is now trying to continuously load the URL with every single keystroke and my app stops working.

```
@State private var text = ""
@State private var site = "www.google.com/"


var body: some View {

let webView = WebView(site: $site, text: $text)

    TextField("Enter a URL", text: Binding(
                    get: { text },
                               set: { newValue in
                                   if trim(newValue).starts(with: "https://") {
                                       text = String(trim(newValue).dropFirst(8))
                                   } else {
                                       text = newValue
                                   }
                               }), onCommit: {
                                
            guard !text.isEmpty else {return}
            site = text
        })
webView //To display the loaded web page

}

     func trim(_ str: String) -> String {
            return str.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        }
```

WebView

```
struct WebView: NSViewRepresentable {
@Binding var site: String
private var webView: WKWebView


init(site: Binding<String>, text: Binding<String>) {
    self.webView = WKWebView()
    _site = site // 
    
}

func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    return webView
}

func updateNSView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    nsView.load(URLRequest(url: (URL(string: "https://" + site) ?? Bundle.main.url(forResource: "URLError", withExtension: "pdf")!)))
}
```

Comment: show us the code where WebKit is trying to continuously load the url.

Comment: When things get more complex, consider to use a ViewModel where you handle the whole data related aspect and logic and let the view just render values.

Comment: @workingdog added the code to post

Comment: I see the error message you posted, but I do no see the code where WebKit is trying to continuously load the url. I suspect your are using "text" for this, where you should be using "site"

Comment: @workingdog i've added all my code. The WebView works perfectly fine with the first textfield in the question. It's only after trying to use the trimming function that you showed me earlier with the 2nd textfield in this post that's bringing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, deleted my previous code as it was not appropriate for Big Sur 11.3 targeting macOS 10.15.

It could be that you get continuous updates because "text" is continuously updated in:

```
let webView = WebView(site: $site, text: $text)
```

remove the "text" part, which you don't use and adjust "WebView" init  accordingly:

```
let webView = WebView(site: $site)
```

EDIT 2:

For completeness, here is my test code that works on macos 12 (because that's the only one I have)
but should work on macos 11.3. It uses an ObservableObject to make the binding work.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import WebKit


extension String {
    func trim() -> String {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}

class WebStateModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var url: URL? = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
    
    func updateUrl(_ str: String) {
        if let theUrl = URL(string: "https://" + WebStateModel.stripHttps(str)) {
            url = theUrl
        }
    }
    
    static func stripHttps(_ str: String) -> String {
        var txt = str.trim()
        if txt.starts(with: "https://") {
            txt = String(txt.dropFirst(8))
        }
        return txt
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var webModel = WebStateModel()
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 80) {
            TextField("Enter a URL", text: Binding(
                get: { text },
                set: { text = WebStateModel.stripHttps($0) } ), onCommit: {
                    webModel.updateUrl(text)
                })
            WebView(webModel: webModel)
        }
    }
}

struct WebView: NSViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var webModel: WebStateModel

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let wkWebview = WKWebView()
        if let theUrl = webModel.url {
            let request = URLRequest(url: theUrl, cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataElseLoad)
            wkWebview.load(request)
        }
        return wkWebview
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if let theUrl = webModel.url {
            let request = URLRequest(url: theUrl, cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataElseLoad)
            nsView.load(request)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think OP is on macOS, not on iOS. UIView/NSView. :)

Comment: @workingdog the whole page now refreshes each time i type a letter in the URL bar.

Comment: works very well for me, no page refresh when I type a letter in the url bar. The url is only updated onCommit. What system are you on and targeting?

Comment: I'm on Big Sur 11.3 targeting macOS 10.15

Comment: updated my answer and added code for macos